# How to download the file based on the file path saved in database?

Tags: javascript, ajax, download, coldfusion

In one of my applications users have an option to upload the document. In that process I upload the document on the server in specific folder and save the path in database column. After process successfully saved the file path column looks like this:

```
C:\wwwroot\myapp\documents\Document 03072017.pdf
```

This path should give me direct access to this file. However, now I have administrator portal where they should be able to download the file. Each record in database is saved with unique key. The document above for example has `key` column with the value `09824982`. When I show records on the screen for administrators, I would only show the icon for the document type. For example if document is `pdf` they will see pdf icon. If document does not exist for that record then it will be blank. My question is what is the best way to process the download int his case? Ideally I do not want to show the document path to the user. If they use dev tools I do not want to display that document root. Is there approach to download the file based on the `key` that I showed above? For example send ajax request with that key and then look up in the database record pull the path and download the document? I use `JavaScript/JQuery` with `ColdFusion 10` and `Oracle` database. In the past I used ColdFusion to download/deliver files to the browser. This time I have single page app and CF is only used on the back end. If anyone can provide some example or suggestion please let me know.

Comment: There is [`<cfcontent>` with the `file` attribute](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-c/cfcontent.html) to passthrough a file stream to a client (a.k.a. download). Right now, your question is too broad for a concrete answer.

Comment: A side note: you can store a token that represents the root location of the data directory, like “%fsRoot%/documents/filename.pdf” and that way you can move your data anywhere and the DB won’t need to be updated.

Comment: If what you did in the past was effective, keep doing it.

Comment: @Alex Can you please provide some example? I have been working with cfcontent in the past. The only way that worked for me it was on `.cfm` file/page. I never seen that used in `.cfc` and `cffunction`. Is that even possible?

Comment: @espresso_coffee `cfcontent` writes directly to the output buffer, so as long as you allow your function to write to it by having `output="true"`, it should work.

Comment: @Alex I have tried putting that in cffunction and response that I get looks like this: /9j/4RP+RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAJAA8BAgAGxx+.... I read in few other blogs that this can't be done via ajax call. I'm not sure if something changed since then.

Comment: Why do you need ajax? Why not just point a link to the download page (using cfcontent to serve up the file)? Also, please add the code you tried to the question so someone can spot what's wrong.

Comment: Never mind. Didn't see how old this thread was ...